# BindableProperty notify property changed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On a custom `ContentView` I have created a `BindableProperty` like this

```
public static readonly BindableProperty StrokeColorProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create("StrokeColor", 
                            typeof(Color), 
                            typeof(SignaturePadView), 
                            Color.Black, 
                            BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

But I have to notify on property change, as I have to read the property in a custom Renderer, how can I do this? 
If I set it on the `PropertyChanged` for `BindableProperty` it  is a static method, so I can not take it from that way :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The PropertyChanged event handler for the BindableProperty will indeed be static, but the input parameters on it are

```
BindingPropertyChangedDelegate<in TPropertyType>(BindableObject bindable, TPropertyType oldValue, TPropertyType newValue);
```

so as you can see, the first input parameter will be a BindableObject. You can safely cast bindable into your custom class and get the instance who's property has changed. like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty StrokeColorProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create("StrokeColor", 
                            typeof(Color), 
                            typeof(SignaturePadView), 
                            Color.Black, 
                            BindingMode.TwoWay,
propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
                {
                    var spv = (SignaturePadView)b;
                    //do something with spv
                    //o is the old value of the property
                    //n is the new value
                });
```

This shows the correct way to catch the property change in shared code where the property is decalred. If you have a custom renderer in the native project, it's OnElementPropertyChanged event **will** fire, with "StrokeColor" as the PropertyName, with or without this propertyChanged delegate being supplied to the BindableProperty definition.

Comment: So I have to do it like this `var spv = bindable as SignaturePadView; spv? .OnPropertyChanged("StrokeColor")`. Why does it not call it automatically?

Comment: How would a property change event ever trigger if there isn't an instance of SignaturePadView who's property had changed? Direct cast should be perfectly safe and clear in intent.

Comment: You are right ;) 
But even though I call it that way `OnElementPropertyChanged` is not called with that parameter-name. Oh, I figured it out; the Renderer is first changed after the `BindableProperties`

Comment: I just showed you how to properly catch the actual property change in the shared code, which you complained was not possible since it's static. I wasn't even trying to figure out why your renderer is not catching it. Can you verify that the render has been correctly registered and is actually used to render your custom control? Also verify that you are actually changing the property in question and that the bindableproperty changed event is firing.

Comment: I have created a small test program where i exactly copy pasted your bindable property definition. I then added a custom renderer in the droid project for it, and sure enough, it's OnElementPropertyChanged event fired as soon as i updated the "StrokeColor" property on my custom control. So either your renderer is not setup, or you are not changing the property.

Comment: to set the new value to current property 
 private static void OnChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var control = bindable as SAIcon;
                if (control == null) return;
                control.IconBackgroundColor = (Color)newvalue;
            });
        }

Answer (score 0):

Override  `OnElementPropertyChanged` method on your Renderer:

```
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if(e.PropertyName=="StrokeColor")
            DoSomething();
    }
```

Comment: It never gets called with that `PropertyName`

Comment: How do I get the old value?